# Initialize c++ multi dimensional vector with multi dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have

```
  float viewerMatrix[4][4] =
    {
      {0.99962944, -0.023989394, -0.012864082, -0.032067116},
      {0.02354476, 0.9991557, -0.033667795, -0.0060634422},
      {0.013660891, 0.033352438, 0.99935031, 0.047027141},
      {   0, 0, 0, 1}
    };
```

I wanted to store this in a class, and there will be many more of these so I thought putting it in `vector` is a good idea. I need to convert this array into `vector<vector<float>>` and then after that `push_back` into a class member that is of type `vector< vector<vector<float>> >`.

So, can I initialize `vector<vector<float>>` with that array?
What I tried

`vector<vector<float>> floatVector (viewerMatrix);`

Does not work.

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘float (*)[4]’ to ‘std::vector<std::vector<float> >::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Why do you need it to initalize it from the intermediate array?

Comment: It is the output from other method that I have no control. It output 2 dimensional array and I wanted to store this result in my own class.

Comment: Well, you need to copy in a loop then, there's no direct conversion available.

Comment: No, it's not a good idea to use `vector` for small fixed-size arrays.

Comment: Then do you have any suggestions to store many 2 dimensional arrays in a class member?

Comment: You can try [another constructor](https://ideone.com/2vslgk).

Comment: `std::array` would be a better choice. Failing that, roll your own matrix-storage class based on C-style arrays. It's not hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of doing this is a memory layout: two dimensional C array [4][4] is located in memory as 16 (4*4) floats like float[16] array. But vector of vector located in other way: it is more similar like float** dynamic array and every element of type float* is allocated separately. It means you cannot just pass a pointer of your two dimensional array and be good. But you can use STL algorithms.

First of all `std::vector` and plain C array both are STL compatible. Let's say you need initialize `std::vector` with one dimentional C array. I must write something like this:

```
float testArray[4]={0.99962944, -0.023989394, -0.012864082, -0.032067116};
vector<float> testVector(testArray,testArray+4);
```

It will construct a new vector and iterate from `testArray` (it's a pointer) to `testArray+4` (it's a pointer too) and `push_back` every element into `testVector`. So the easiest way to achieve what you want is:

```
vector<vector<float>> floatVector{
    {viewerMatrix[0],viewerMatrix[0]+4},
    {viewerMatrix[1],viewerMatrix[1]+4},
    {viewerMatrix[2],viewerMatrix[2]+4},
    {viewerMatrix[3],viewerMatrix[3]+4},
};
```

Of course 4 value in dimensions can be changed so it is better to create a function that takes a two dimensional array of any number of elements and returns `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`. For example:

```
template<size_t M,size_t N>
std::vector<std::vector<float>> initVectorWithTwoDimArray(float (&ar)[M][N]){
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> res;
    res.reserve(M);
    for(auto i=0;i<M;++i){
        res.emplace_back(ar[i],ar[i]+N);
    }
    return std::move(res);
}

float viewerMatrix[4][4] =
{
    {0.99962944, -0.023989394, -0.012864082, -0.032067116},
    {0.02354476, 0.9991557, -0.033667795, -0.0060634422},
    {0.013660891, 0.033352438, 0.99935031, 0.047027141},
    {   0, 0, 0, 1}
};

auto floatVector=initVectorWithTwoDimArray(viewerMatrix);
```

Now `floatVector` is `std::vector` of `std::vector<float>` contained your two dim array.

**Edit**

If you like this function it can be recreated with array of any type not just `float`:

```
template<class T,size_t M,size_t N>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> initVectorWithTwoDimArray(T (&ar)[M][N]){
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> res;
    res.reserve(M);
    for(auto i=0;i<M;++i){
        res.emplace_back(ar[i],ar[i]+N);
    }
    return std::move(res);
}
```

This version will work for any type of arrays: `int`, `double`, `AnyYourClass` etc. Usage is the same:

```
float viewerMatrix[4][4] =
{
    {0.99962944, -0.023989394, -0.012864082, -0.032067116},
    {0.02354476, 0.9991557, -0.033667795, -0.0060634422},
    {0.013660891, 0.033352438, 0.99935031, 0.047027141},
    {   0, 0, 0, 1}
};

auto floatVector=initVectorWithTwoDimArray(viewerMatrix);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have `vector` of array. If you really need to store the output in the `vector`, I would say make a something like

```
class Matrix
{
float m[4][4];
};
```

And then copy your stuff over and push it into the `vector`.

Comment: Why not `std::array<std::array<float,4>,4> m;`?

Comment: I just prefer c-style arrays in this case. From what I know there should not be any performance penalties when using container.